# Qual è il senso di "ostante" in questo brano?

Tags: meaning

Nel libro *Racconto d'autunno*, di Tommaso Landolfi, ho letto:

> Confesso che mi venne la tentazione di saltargli addosso, ma
>   ne fui distolto da due ordini di considerazioni. Il primo assai poco
>   onorevole, e fu il pericolo che avrei corso a farlo: i cani infatti,
>   anche stavolta presenti, vedendo il padrone scuotermi in quel
>   modo già mi si avvicinavano minacciosi. Il secondo, più meritorio, riguardava tutte le buone ragioni **ostanti** di umanità, gratitudine eccetera. Così poste le cose, l'unica era subire con filosofia il rabbuffo.

Alla [voce "ostare" del vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ostare) ho trovato che "ostante" significa

> che è d’impedimento, che si oppone

e le definizioni che ho visto in altri dizionari sono simili. Tuttavia, non riesco a capire il senso di questo "ostanti" che appare nel testo sopra citato. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Comment: Il termine *ostante* si trova ormai solo nella locuzione *nonostante*, se si escludono i testi di carattere legale.

Comment: @egreg: So che a Landolfi piaceva usare termini desueti.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il significato è quello che hai trovato tu.

Le ragioni ostanti sono quelle che impediscono al narratore di saltare addosso al padrone dei cani.

Infatti aveva, in primo luogo, paura della reazione dei cani e inoltre la sua umanità e la gratitudine frenavano questo suo istinto, cioè si opponevano, erano di impedimento.

Puoi intendere il significato della frase così:

> Il secondo, più meritorio, riguardava tutte le buone ragioni ostanti:
>   umanità, gratitudine, eccetera.

L'autore intende elencare le ragioni buone, meritorie che lo trattengono dall'agire.